# Regular expression: repeating patterns in the beginning of string

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

For example, consider the following string: `"apple1: apple2: apple3: some random words here apple4:"`

I want to match only apple1, apple2 and apple3 but not apple4. I am having a hard time to figure out how to archive this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is so special about not matching `apple4`? Is there a rule to this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? apple1 and apple2 is not a repeated word. Do you want to match A-Z characters followed by optional NON a-z characters, and only match on those bits? Does "apple1 apple1: apple apple! apple? apple?yes!apple!" match or not?

Comment: The problem needs a more complete specification. Without that, there are too many possible answers. For example, you might say you want to match words separated by whitespace until one word doesn't match.

Comment: Basically, I only want to match apple with digits in the beginning of the string, that's why apple4 is ignored. And I don't know how many occurrences it will have in the string, it can have apple1: apple2: ... apple30: random word... apple31: and apple31 will not be matched

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net you can match the below pattern and then use the `Captures` property of the group to get all the different apples matched along the way.

```
(?:(apple\d).*?){3}
```

If you only want to match the first one:

```
apple\d
```

Sweet and simple. Just call match on this once.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i am using python, and I only want to only match apple\d in the beginning of the string, and I don't how many occurrence of apple it can have in the string

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it sounds like you want to match the occurrences of `apple` followed by a digit throughout the string except an occurrence of `apple` followed by a digit at the end of the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> text    = 'apple1: apple2: apple3: some random words here apple4:'
>>> matches = re.findall(r'(\bapple\d+):(?!$)', text)

['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3']
```

Answer (score 1):

So, maybe something like this:

```
^([A-Za-z]+)[^A-Za-z]+(\1[^A-Za-z]+)+
```

http://regexr.com/38vvb

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I did not format my question properly, it wasn't clear.

I found the solution:

```
r'\s*((apple)\d+[ \:\,]*)+'
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You don't need to escape those characters. `r'\s*((apple)\d+[ :,]*)+'`